# Question about closed curves and surfaces

Tags: geometry, implicit-differentiation, curves

Let $\mathbb{r}:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be  a continuous non-intersecting loop (i.e. $\mathbb{r}(a)=\mathbb{r}(b)$ and $\mathbb{r}(x)\neq\mathbb{r}(y),\ \forall \{x,y\}\neq\{a,b\}$). Denote by $D$ the open domain enclosed by $\mathbb{r}$. Prove or disprove that there is a continuous function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $F(x,y)=0$ iff $(x,y)\in \partial D$ and $F(x,y)<0$ iff $(x,y)\in D$.

Comment: Since the domain is regular, you can solve the equation $\Delta u = 0$, in that domain when $u = 1$ on the border.
Then the maximum principle tells you that $u<1$ in all the domain. So take $u-1$ and you're done.

EDIT: I actually don't know about that iff part. It is certainly possible in some examples, but I don't know what happens outside of the domain in the general case.

Comment: Can this be generalized for closed non-intersecting surfaces enclosing solids?

Comment: Yep, $\Delta u = 0 $ is solved in $\mathbb{R}^3$ too

Answer (score 1):

The "difficult part" in this connection is the fact that $K:=r\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$ separates ${\Bbb R}^2$ into two disjoint open sets $D$ and $\Omega$, one of them (named $D$) bounded. This is the *Jordan curve theorem*.

In order to construct a function $F: \>{\Bbb R}^2\to{\Bbb R}$ of the required kind we make use of the following fact: Given a compact set $K\subset {\Bbb R}^2$ the function $$x\mapsto d(x,K):=\inf_{y\in K} |y-x|$$
("distance from $x$ to $K$") is continuous. Given this, put
$$F(x):=\left\{\eqalign{-d(x,K)\qquad&(x\in D) \cr
d(x,K)\qquad&(x\in\Omega)\ .\cr}\right.$$